# redux dispatch return they own parameter instead of new value

Tags: redux, dispatch

I don't know why, but my redux dispatch return they own parameters, no new value. There is really simple ptoject because I try to learn redux and I have really big problem with understand it.

my reducer:

```
var initialState = {
    number: 3
}

var reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD':
        return {
            ...state,
            number: state.number + action.number
        }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

  export default reducer
```

store.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducers/reducer-test'

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

index.js:

```
import store from './store/store';

console.log("state", store.getState());
console.log("new val", store.dispatch({type: 'ADD', number: 5}); // give me {type: 'ADD', number: 5}, and should something different
```

Comment: Try this: `console.log("state", store.getState()); store.dispatch({type: 'ADD', number: 5}); console.log("state", store.getState());` The issue is `dispatch` does not return the new state.

Comment: aaa, ok. So I have to get state once again. My really big misunderstaood. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help out!